# Error ORA-25448 when creating job chain rule using dbms_scheduler.define_chain_rule

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dbms-scheduler

When I attempt to create the following oracle chain rule:

```
BEGIN
   SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE (
     chain_name   =>   'MIGRATE_EISDB_CHAIN',
     condition    =>   ':MIGRATION_STEP_1.state=''RUNNING'' AND select decode(TIME_COMPLETED, null, 0, 1) from MIGRATION_PROGRESS where MIGRATION_STEP = "MIGRATE_AEP_TO_EP" > 0',
     rule_name    =>   'continue_migration',
     action       =>   'START MIGRATION_STEP_2',
     comments     =>   'continue the migration - step 2');
END;
```

/

The chain, steps and the first rule were created successfully, but I 
get this error when creating the second rule with a condition:

> Error report - 
>  ORA-25448: rule EISYSNEW1.CONTINUE_MIGRATION has
>   errors
>  ORA-00936: missing expression
>  ORA-06512: at
>   "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 1646
>  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER",
>   line 1619
>  ORA-06512: at line 2
>   25448. 00000 -  "The %s %s.%s has errors."
>   *Cause:    An attempt to load the specified rule or expression failed due
>              to errors in the rule or expression.
>   *Action:   Check the rule or expression and retry the operation.

Question:

Why is this happening??  Oracle's documentation says that this condition should be legal.  What am I missing in the expression for this condition??  FYI: It does create when I omit the part after the 'AND'.

```
condition    =>   ':MIGRATION_STEP_1.state=''RUNNING'' AND select decode(TIME_COMPLETED, null, 0, 1) from MIGRATION_PROGRESS where MIGRATION_STEP = "MIGRATE_AEP_TO_EP" > 0',
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where Oracle's documentation says that the condition is legal.  It doesn't look too legal to me.

You need to make the nested `SELECT` a subquery, by wrapping it in parentheses.  Unless `MIGRATE_AEP_TO_EP` is a column name, you may also want to replace the double-quotes around `MIGRATE_AEP_TO_EP` to single quotes.  As the rule itself is a string literal, you will need to escape each of the single quotes with a second single quote, as you have with `RUNNING`:

```
 condition    =>   ':MIGRATION_STEP_1.state=''RUNNING'' AND (select decode(TIME_COMPLETED, null, 0, 1) from MIGRATION_PROGRESS where MIGRATION_STEP = ''MIGRATE_AEP_TO_EP'') > 0',
```